# O que é Overfitting e Underfitting em Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

O que é *Overfitting* e *Underfitting* em *Machine Learning*? Estou estudando um pouco sobre o assunto e fiquei curioso onde isso se aplica.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Overfitting**(sobreajuste ou superajuste) e **Underfitting**(sub-ajuste) em Machine Learning são conceitos que se referem ao ajuste do modelo. Para entender esses conceitos, é importante conhecer os tipos de aprendizado de máquina existente: Aprendizagem por Reforço, Supervisionado e Não Supervisionado.

No aprendizado supervisionado, os algoritmos de Machine Learning ajustam os parâmetros das funções para que elas satisfaçam as condições dadas pelos valores das etiquetas. Esse ajuste é conhecido como "*model fit*" e é realizado durante o treinamento do modelo com base nos dados. Quando o modelo já está treinado, é possível realizar previsões com o modelo ajustado, o que é chamado de "*model predict*".

Essa compreensão orientará você a tomar medidas corretivas. Pode-se determinar se um modelo preditivo está fazendo o sub-ajuste ou o sobreajuste dos dados de treinamento consultando o erro de previsão nos dados de treinamento e nos dados de avaliação. Compreender o ajuste de modelo é importante para entender a causa raiz da precisão de modelo insatisfatória.

- O *overfitting* ocorre quando o modelo se adaptou muito bem aos dados
  de treinamento, mas não generaliza bem para novos dados, ou seja, não
  consegue lidar com dados que não foram vistos durante o treinamento.
  Isso acontece porque o modelo "decorou" o conjunto de dados de
  treinamento, mas não aprendeu os padrões importantes para generalizar
  para novos dados.
- Já o *underfitting* ocorre quando o modelo não se adapta bem sequer
  aos dados de treinamento. Isso acontece quando o modelo é muito
  simples em relação aos dados que está tentando modelar, e não
  consegue.

Veja no gráfico como são representados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referências

1. [Ajuste do modelo: subajuste versus sobreajuste](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/machine-learning/latest/dg/model-fit-underfitting-vs-overfitting.html)
2. [Refinamento de Algoritmos de Aprendizado de Máquina](https://slideplayer.com.br/slide/12445128/)

Answer (score 4):

Overfitting (sobre-ajuste) é um termo usado em estatística para descrever quando um modelo estatístico se ajusta muito bem ao conjunto de dados anteriormente observado, mas se mostra ineficaz para prever novos resultados.

É comum que a amostra apresente desvios causados por erros de medição ou fatores aleatórios. Ocorre o sobre ajuste quando o modelo se ajusta a estes. Um modelo sobre-ajustado apresenta alta precisão quando testado com seu conjunto de dados, porém tal modelo não é uma boa representação da realidade e por isso deve ser evitado. É bem comum que estes modelos apresentem considerável variância e que seus gráficos tenham várias pequenas oscilações, portanto espera-se que modelos representativos sejam convexos.

Uma ferramenta para contornar o problema do sobre-ajuste é a regularização, que adiciona à função custo o valor dos parâmetros. Tal adição resulta na eliminação de parâmetros de pouca importância e, portanto, em um modelo mais convexo, do qual que se espera que seja mais representativo da realidade. Através da validação cruzada, em que testamos o nosso modelo em relação a uma parte reservada do conjunto de dados que não foi utilizada no treino do modelo em questão, é possível se ter uma ideia de se o modelo sofre de sobre-ajuste ou não.

Underfitting, a contrapartida do overfitting, acontece quando um modelo de aprendizado de máquina não é complexo o suficiente para capturar com precisão as relações entre os recursos de um conjunto de dados e uma variável de destino. Um modelo insuficiente resulta em resultados problemáticos ou errôneos em novos dados, ou dados nos quais não foi treinado, e muitas vezes tem um desempenho ruim, mesmo em dados de treinamento.

Fontes: https://www.datarobot.com/wiki/underfitting/
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreajuste